# Searches for Chinese characters in Sqlite database with PHP don't match

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I'm having some trouble getting PHP to match queries of Chinese characters in an SQLite database. The same search when done in sqlite3 from the command prompt yields a hit, but PHP shows nothing.

The code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');
$sql=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM character WHERE character='安';");
$sql->execute();
$result=$sql->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

This shows an empty array. When I search for any other field(not a Chinese character), it will show the correct result.

For laughs, I set the headers to utf-8, 16, 16BE, 16LE(just flailing), but this did nothing.

The data type for the field is set as nchar, but setting it to text gives no different result. Similarly, using SQLite3 instead of PDO makes no change.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex('安');` in the shell and from PHP?

Comment: @CL In the shell it gives: 88C0, in PHP it shows: hex('螳').

Comment: And when you *execute* it from PHP?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Ah, I see. PHP gives 'E5AE89'. [hex('螳')] => E5AE89 Is the full line. The character that is produced there is different from the original input: 安. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no easy answer, but it isn't a problem with the Windows console, as the database handles all input, from browser or console in the same manner.  Despite sources saying that sqlite can use utf-8, it appears to work in ucs-2, an encoding I have no knowledge of. I verified this by decoding and encoding ucs to utf.

The easy answer, and the one I took, as I couldn't get the encoding to jive, was to just use base64_encode on queries going into the database, and decode on information coming out. It's not elegant, but it allows utf characters into a non-utf database.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Windows console does not correctly handle UTF-8 input/output.
Any data you have entered or edited in the console is some wrong encoding.

You could try to execute `chcp 65001` before running `sqlite3.exe`, but you'd better use some other SQLite tool that handles UTF-8 correctly in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! That is a very inconvenient feature. I just tried a few things and noticed, though, that if I search for another field in PHP(a non-chinese character field), it will display the command prompt entered data correctly, but if I add the information through PHP, and then search for it in the same manner, it displays the incorrect data. Do you know if perhaps some setting in PHP might fix this? Thanks again.